# Excel Update value in continent based on values in country

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Hi I have a column in excel called country which has the country already filled in I need to write some sort of Logic to fill the column in the Continent column.

Eg in the country the values may be Germany, France, Belgium, UK. Is there any way that by some logic I can select some predefined values" these list of countries belong to Europe"  and enter automatically update the continent column p.s. I have about 35000 entries so manually doing it is not the best option thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a lookup table and then apply the VLOOKUP formula:

- Insert a new worksheet into your workbook (e.g. `Countries`)
- Enter all relevant countries in column and its continent in column
- In your source table, place the following formula (assuming that you country name is in column A, starting in row 2): `=VLOOKUP(A2,Countries!$A:$B,2,0)`
- Copy the formula down
- Use an AutoFilter and check for `#N/A` errors in the new column. For these countries, the VLOOKUP could not find a match in your new table. Add these values and assign a continent.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, @PeterAlbert 's answer wouldn't really work as-is since you don't have a completed table with the corresponding "continent" values to match up against.  In this case, I would recommend that you first obtain a table with which you can then perform any lookup functions, and the most painless way that I can think of would be to search for one – via your choice of search engine – and then insert the table by importing it; refer to screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

There are varying options and settings you might want to mess with, and depending on which version of O365 you have Excel's capabilities may vary by quite a bit.  Once it's been imported, you can then perform the necessary analyses to output what you need.

PS: I would use "list of countries by continent" as the search term, if that helps.